# Getting Session in Http Handler ashx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I am using Http Handler ashx file for showing the images. 
I was using Session object to get image and return in the response

Now problem is i need to use custom Session object its nothing but the Wrapper on HttpSession State But when i am trying to get existing custom session object its creating new ... 
its not showing session data , i checked the session Id which is also different 
Please adive how can i get existing session in ashx file ?

Note: When i use ASP.NET Sesssion its working fine

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class GetImage : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
    {
```

Comment: are you marking your handler with IRequiresSessionState ?

Comment: thanks for the response , Yes, i copied the code in the main question .. 
Please have look

Answer (score 2):

When you want to get access to your Session State from an ASHX or HttpHandler you need to implement IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState if you need read/write access.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's an ashx should be irrelevant - assuming the request is being spawned off a request from an exsiting session; I'm assuming it should be - but it might pay to check exactly how the request is being formed.  Always pays to go back to basics :)

Assuming that's ok, this is how I've been doing it:

```
string sessionId = string.Empty; 
System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager sessionIDManager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
bool supportSessionIDReissue;
sessionIDManager.InitializeRequest(httpContext, false, out supportSessionIDReissue); sessionId = sessionIDManager.GetSessionID(httpContext);
if (sessionId == null)
{
 // Create / issue new session id: 
 sessionId = sessionIDManager.CreateSessionID(httpContext);
}
```

At the end of this the sessionId variable will (should) contain the existing Session ID, or a newly created one that you can reuse later..

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a Actionresult rather than a handler for this

```
return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
```

or

return(new FileResult(Pathtoimage, "image/jpeg"));

that should make things easier as you wil be using a controll/action as your url

ie

```
<img src="/Images/showImage/1">
```

you can then have your actions deal with anything like pulling from db as bytes
streaming, check validation etc

Comment: I believe this would only work with ASP.NET MVC. The OP was in regards to a custom HttpHandler. There are no controllers nor actions...

Comment: the question is an asp.net mvc question !!! also he said he was trying to get an image comming from winforms he prob used a httpHandler to do that, but MVC is a design pattern so why break the pattern, the pattern works fine without having to use any httpHandler as this is replaced by the Controller / Action and wouldent you be better leaving a solution !!!!

Comment: your solution will workt .. but what will be the path for the image ? i can't store image at server side .. again controller doing this will take more time as compare to http handler